# Opening lazy loaded router link in a modal or a new page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-router

I have a app.routing.ts file as below

```
    import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { SalesComponent } from './advisory/sales.component';

    const appRoutes: Routes = [
        {
            path:'admin',loadChildren:'./auth/admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
        },
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: '/main',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
            path: 'main', component: SalesComponent,
            data: { apptitle: 'main', subtitle: 'main' }
        },

    ];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, 
        { useHash: true },
        )],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

App.component.html

```
<router-outlet name="app-popup"></router-outlet>
```

And a feature module admin.module.ts file as below

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { AdminComponent } from './admin.component';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{
         path:'index',
        component: AdminComponent,
        outlet: 'app-popup',
    }
    ]),

    declarations: [AdminComponent]
    })

    export class AdminModule { }
```

Admin.component.html

```
<span class="title">Login</span>

<div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="loginmodal-container">
              <h1>Login to Your Account</h1><br>
            <form>
              <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
              <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
              <input type="submit" name="login" class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Login">
            </form>

            <div class="login-help">
              <a href="#">Register</a> - <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have a xyz component where I am trying to launch the AdminComponent in a model dialog like below on a button click

```
<button [routerLink]="[ '', { outlets: { 'app-popup': ['index'] } }] "  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal" ></button>
```

When I click the button, it shows the Login title at the bottom of the page but the login modal dialog does not open.  This is all new to me. Any tips on how to open this lazy loaded router link in a modal and a new page would be much appreciated.